# What happens when a rider dies of old age?

Tags: dragonriders-of-pern, anne-mccaffrey

In the Pern novels, what happens when a rider dies of old age? Does the dragon go *between* without them? It's implied that dragons never die of old age themselves, so I'm asking about the riders.

As a second note, is this ever recorded in the books?  I would assume that there would be something about the Oldtimers dying off, but as far as I can tell they just *do*, without much explanation.

Answer (score 2):

In *Moreta: Dragonlady of Pern,* when Moreta and Holth die *between* because they were too exhausted to envision their destination properly, Orlith (Moreta's queen) stays only long enough to see her eggs reach the Hatching Grounds, and then goes *between* on her own the morning of Impression. McCaffrey describes how Orlith is writhing on the ground in agony immediately after Moreta's loss because she *can't* go *between* just yet, until her eggs hatch.

When Robinton dies of old age at the end of *All the Weyrs of Pern,* his fire-lizard Zair dies as well (although he doesn't go *between,* oddly enough; he just lies on Robinton's chest and dies). Dragons were bred from fire-lizards with genetic enhancements, so there's a strong correlation in their behavior.

Beyond that, I don't recall reading about any riders who die dragonless and leave the dragon around to re-Impress. There are several riders who lose dragons and don't die, Lytol/L'tol and Brekke being the most prominent, but not the reverse.

Comment: Robinton doesn't die of old age, he dies from a bad heart.  And Moreta & Holth died from exhaustion, not due to old age.  I'm looking for cases when they simply died of old age, not because of complications old age (in Robinton's case) caused them.

Comment: @Riker No, I understood that. I'm simply citing the only instances I can recall at *all* where the rider died before the dragon, of any reason, and then what happened. The only person, period, I can think of who died of old age on screen was Kitti Ping from *Dragonsdawn.* (I admit it's been a while since I read the books, so feel free to cite other examples.) The dragonriders have inherently dangerous lives; I only recall one example of one who was old enough to have retired, and his name escapes me at the moment. McCaffrey simply may not have written the circumstances you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

I remember that duels were stopped at first blood, because if a dragon rider died, his dragon would go between. I think that was when F'lar and Lessa came dressed in green to the fair, but F'lar dueled with the oldtimer, thread was falling somewhere, and F'lar gained ascendancy. The comment was something like, "He isn't dead; the dragon is still here."

Comment: This doesn't answer my question about what happens when a rider dies of _old age_.  Yes, we can assume that the same happens as with any other death, but I'm looking for direct evidence that it does.

Comment: Also, welcome to literature.SE!

Comment: Thanks, and I see what you mean. I made the assumption that the same would be true of old age, but don't have direct evidence.